# how to remove/hide GWT Tabpanel header

Tags: gwt

I have this attached tabPanel , I want to remove this gray area, or make it white .. 
Any idea how can i achieve this .

thanks 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily change it from CSS add these lines with desired color:

```
.gwt-TabBar .gwt-TabBarRest{

 }
```

Check [TabBar](https://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabBar.html)'s CSS Style Rules for more information.

PS: If you use [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29), you can find such stuffs without asking from someone else.